# Creating a checkerboard in Java using a while loop

Tags: java, loops

The goal is to create an ASCII checkerboard using the following pattern:

```
+--+
|  |
+--+
```

I have used the following code in Java to create a board with n boxes but the problem is that the resulting boxes stack vertically like a line when I pass n argument:

```
+--+
|  |
+--+
+--+
|  |
+--+
```

I want the boxes to iterate across lines so it forms a checkerboard like pattern like 
this:

```
+--+--+
|  |  |
+--+--+
|  |  |
+--+--+
```

The Java code is:

```
public class Checkerboard {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int x = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    printBoard(x);
}


public static void printBox(int numOfBoxes) {

    int i = 0;
    while(i < numOfBoxes)
    i++;    
     System.out.print("+--+");
     System.out.println("|  |");
     System.out.println("+--+");
}
```

}

Any input would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your question?  It may seem obvious to you, but be less obvious to others.

Comment: Maybe you should get the user to input two numbers, a height and width so you know how to draw the boxes?

Comment: Well I want to know how I can modify the code within loop so instead of the boxes stacking up vertically I can make them iterate across lines.

Comment: It'll be a substantial modification.  You'll have to generate the strings, then print them.  Your current problem is that printing a box uses println, which means you've already moved to the next line.

Comment: I've down-voted because I don't see any evidence that you've actually tried to solve the problem yourself. It feels a little like we're being asked to solve your homework :-)

Comment: You will either have to provide width and height or divide the input number by 2 to determine width and height.  You will then need another iterator to draw horizontally as well as vertically.  Draw the left side only when you are drawing the first box in a row and draw the top only when you are drawing the first row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could build something along this pseudo code:

```
for y=0 to 3 * ysize
   for x=0 to 3 * xsize
      if x even and y even
        print +
      if x even and y odd
        print |
      if x odd  and y even
        print --
      if x odd  and y odd
        print space space
```

I don't think a single while loop is matching your needs.

If you want to put chess figures on your board later on, you maybe are better off to save your checkerboard into a `StringBuffer` and "render" it to screen ;)

Comment: Hmm this makes a lot of sense. Yeah I realized I need to use more than one loop. Thanks a lot ^_^